# Nested SQL query for games site

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Hi I need help with this query, i am trying to get a list of games that are in a favourites table which is simple enough but I also need the corresponding game cover img from the games table.  i think this need to be done as a nested sql but I really dont know.

```
SELECT  Favourites.Game_platform, Favourites.Game_name, Favourites.Priority, Games.Cover_img
FROM  Favourites INNER JOIN
      Games
      ON Favourites.Game_name = Games.Name
WHERE (Favourites.User_ID = @User_ID) AND (Favourites.Game_name = Game.Name)
```

I think it needs to store the favourites game_name and get the cover image where favourite game name is games name.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/42f61

Comment: Your query looks fine, except for the fact that none of your tables have a column called `cover_img`.  Where does it come from?

Comment: What is the issue you are having?

Comment: is cover_img in another table?  I don't see it in your sql fiddle

Comment: I dont't see `Cover_img` column  in the games table, how you can get it, if have not defined it in the **Games** table.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: @Jeremy Danyow Sorry that is an older database, this is the correct one http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/42f61 .. I have no data in it at the mo because it makes it over 8000 characters, if anyone wants a copy to test it with the data I can put the script on skydrive are something.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i am using ms sql 2008 within visual studio

Comment: @Matt The issue is when i run this it gives me all the cover img but i only need the cover img for the games that are in the users favorite list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT  f.Game_platform, f.Game_name, f.Priority, g.Cover_img
FROM  Favourites f INNER JOIN Games g ON f.Game_name = g.Name
WHERE f.User_ID = @User_ID
```

Comment: Thanks @P5Coder that worked :D I just had to add an and to the on to make sure didnt get same games for all platforms.  SELECT f.Game_platform, f.Game_name, f.Priority, g.Cover_img, g.Name FROM Favourites AS f INNER JOIN Games AS g ON f.Game_name = g.Name AND f.Game_platform = g.Platform WHERE (f.User_ID = @User_ID)